# pfSense Squid Rotate Log at Certain Size - Shell Script

Tags: shell, freebsd, squid, pfsense

Trying to create a shell script to cron at 4am everyday which will read the size of squid's access.log file and rotate it if it is past a certain size (20MB). Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

ymd=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
file=/var/squid/logs/access.log
minimumsize="20000000"
eval $(stat -s /var/squid/logs/access.log)

if [ $st_size > $minimumsize ]; then
    cp /var/squid/logs/access.log /var/squid/logs/access_log_history/access.log.${ymd}
    rm -fr /var/squid/logs/access.log
    squid -k rotate
else
    :
fi
```

The shell script runs but just rotates the log file regardless of size and creates a file named "20000000". That is it. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own shellscript take a look at newsyslog(8) which does the same thing.